# Combining Python dictionary into a string csv

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Dictionary here:

```
dict = {'AB': 1, 'AE': '0', 'CC': '3'}
```

I am trying to get that dictionary into the exact string format:

```
AB1,AE0,CC3
```

I have currently been trying this:

```
string = ",".join(("{},{}".format(*i) for i in dict.items()))
```

But my output has been this:

```
AB,1,AE,0,CC,3
```

Which is just off slightly.

Does anyone know of of a way to format this dictionary correctly into a string?

Thanks

Comment: Just remove that comma inside the join `string = ",".join(("{}{}".format(*i) for i in dict.items()))`. See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/DryFumblingNetbsd)

Comment: Plesse accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Here we go (just delete the comma):

```
d = {'AB': 1, 'AE': '0', 'CC': '3'}

output = ",".join(["{}{}".format(key, value) for key, value in d.items()])
#                   ^^^^
print(output)
```

This yields

```
AB1,AE0,CC3
```

Alternatively with your original unpacking method:

```
output = ",".join(["{}{}".format(*x) for x in d.items()])
```

Also, please do not name your variables after builtin objects (dict, list, tuple, the like).

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
dict = {'AB': 1, 'AE': '0', 'CC': '3'}
string=','.join([i+str(dict[i]) for i in dict])
print(string)
```

output:

```
AB1,AE0,CC3
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to loop over each and every element of the dictionary and then concatenate it’s key and value together. Finally, append this concatenated value to a list.

```
d = {'AB': 1, 'AE': '0', 'CC': '3'}

#initialize an empty list
l=[]
for i in d:
    l.append(str(i)+str(d[i]))
```

Once, this list is obtained, just convert it into a string with its elements separated by comma by using join() function.

```
out = ','.join(l)
print(out)
   'AB1,AE0,CC3'
```

Comment: Hi Ram, just did that. I hope that suffices.

Answer (score 0):

A more functional solution:

```
# don't shadow `dict`
d = {'AB': 1, 'AE': '0', 'CC': '3'}

# `starmap` flattens argument to a function
# needed for `str.format`
from itertools import starmap

# build parts from dictionary items
parts = starmap('{}{}'.format, d.items())

# build end result from parts
result = ','.join(parts)
```

If you want a robust solution you should use the `csv` module and take a look at `DictWriter`

Answer (score 0):

You can use so-called f-strings if you are using Python 3:

```
d = {'AB': 1, 'AE': '0', 'CC': '3'}
out = ','.join([f'{i}{d[i]}' for i in d.keys()])
print(out)
```

output:

```
AB1,AE0,CC3
```

If you want know more about f-strings see this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Keep in mind that this solution works only in Python 3.3 and newer versions.